# Which weapons/shields/items/etc. talk?

Tags: borderlands-2

I came across an [article on Kataku](http://kotaku.com/5952572/my-awesome-new-borderlands-2-gun-wont-stop-judging-me) and it showed a sniper rifle (not sure which one) that actually talked while reloading, and shooting. [Here](http://youtu.be/jlAUpuNAyfQ) is a video the writer posted of it in action.

I actually have a few small questions *(I don't want to spam them in separate questions)*:

- Which weapons/shields/items/etc. talk to you? *(mention if I need DLC)*
- Do the weapons/shields/items/etc. that talk depend on which character you have? *(mention if I need DLC)*

Comment: It's not just weapons either - I've had a shield which talked

Comment: @Robotnik Really? wow. Do you happen to remember the name of it?

Comment: The "1340 Shield" - It was a mission reward. You get the choice between a shotgun (actually the first shotgun in demure's answer) or a shield http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/1340_Shield

Comment: @Robotnik Ya. There should be more weapons that talk (I thin). I'm pretty sure the [talking weapons would be tagged as "unique"](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Unique).

Comment: Related: [Borderlands wiki — Items with voice modules](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Items_with_voice_modules)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am aware of three weapons, and a shield.

#### Weapons

- [Shotgun 1340](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Shotgun_1340)
- [Morningstar](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Morningstar)
- [The Bane](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Bane)

#### Shield

- [1340 Shield](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/1340_Shield)

You can find more borderlands trivia [here](http://borderlands.wikia.com/)

Comment: Well according to the article I linked to (check my question for the link) the weapon he used was called the "Hyperion sniper rifle" so I'm *almost* sure there are more.

Comment: @Scootaloo If you read the article you linked, they refer to it as "... a unique Hyperion sniper rifle...", which is the Morningstar, made by Hyperion. They then suggest it is the "Auditing Morningstar" variation later in the article.

Comment: I mainly skimmed over the article - probably should have paid more attention. [Robotnik said](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119334/which-weapons-talk?noredirect=1#comment160755_119334) that he had a talking shield, assuming he wasn't joking there are probably more talking items/weapons.

Comment: @Scootaloo yes, the [1340 shield](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/1340_Shield) is a variation of the 1340 Shotgun, from the same mission. As your question was about weapons, I did not include it.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: The Bane is hilarious. Especially if you gunzerk while wielding two of them.

Answer (score -1):

List of all guns and shields with voice modules http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Items_with_voice_modules

Comment: I downvoted your answer because you do not provide more informations than the last answer. You should take a look at the tour guide since you seem new: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour